# Reaching elements of an object

Tags: php

How can i reach elements of this object with php? I have tried `$obj[0]->trends` to reach inner array but php gives me error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /.....file.php on line 97`

```
   stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [trends] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => IWorkAsHardAs
                                [query] => IWorkAsHardAs
                                [events] => 
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => ProtectOzoneLayer
                                [query] => ProtectOzoneLayer
                                [events] => 
                            )


                    )

                [as_of] => 2013-09-16T13:06:47Z
                [created_at] => 2013-09-16T12:44:57Z
                [locations] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => Jaipur
                                [woeid] => 2295401
                            )

                    )

            )

        [httpstatus] => 200
    )
```

Comment: Try this: `$obj->{'0'}->trends[0]` or even `$obj->{0}->trends[0]`. Looks like your object has numeric property name.

Comment: @CORRUPT it isn't work to.

Comment: Well, try to cast it to array: `$casted = (array)$obj;`. And then try this: `var_dump($casted);`.

Comment: It is handled @CORRUPT . Thanks.